# GC Variable not working in PowerShell: it doesn't return any results

Tags: powershell, variables, file-get-contents

I've got a .txt file that I'm trying to get-content from, and I'm struggling to turn the gc into a variable...  I'm running:

```
$variablesfile = gc .\Variables.txt
```

I've also put the entire filepath here instead of just .\Variables.txt, and I know I'm in the right directory because ISE is auto-filling the filepath and filename for me...  But when I type $variablesfile it doesn't return any results...  If I just go to PowerShell and type:

```
gc .\Variables.txt
```

it displays the information I want without issue, but I can't seem to declare it as a variable...  Also, when I just type $VariablesFile to get the results, it doesn't see it as an existing variable.

Comment: Could you post the content of Variables.txt or sample data?

Comment: The entire contents:

1am;test4

Comment: Basically, I'm using a different ps1 file to have someone enter variables, which I'm putting into a .txt file, then invoke-command with a new ps1 file to remote servers, where I'm trying to pull those variables back out of the .txt file.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue, I populate the $variablesfile variable without issue. If you're trying to save the data for programatic use, why not save it as a json or clixml file instead? Export-Clixml and ConvertTo-Json would both assist you with that.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to Variables.txt instead of a relative path?

Comment: Thanks guys.  Nothing seemed to work for the variable in this script.  I ended up just creating the script from scratch.  The first thing I did was establish the variable, make sure it worked, then pasted everything else from the old script and it worked.  As far as Export-Clixml and ConvertTo-Json...  Basically I have no clue what I'm doing, so I'm just working with what I know.

Comment: Yeah, something is definitely funky with this script.  I've got it finalized now, but every time I needed add a new variable to it, I had to completely recreate the script and start by establishing the new variables...  Really weird...  Unfortunately, I can't just throw the entire script in here for help, but something is obviously weird with this one.